# How to pass html form values to route variable in slim?

Tags: php, html, frameworks, routes, slim

This is my html form

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="login/login_process">
Username:<input type="text" name="username">
Password:<input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to pass the values username and password to the route variable $username and $password
This is the slim route

```
<?php
require 'vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
require 'Login/login_process.php';
$app->get('/login', function () {
include 'Login/login.php';
});
$app->get('/login/login_process(/:username)(/:password)',     function($username,$password){
echo $username;
echo $password;
});
$app->run();
?>
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Using method *GET* is very bad in logging form**

Comment: Which version of Slim are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use like this
i.e :

```
$app->post('/login', function()
{
    authentication(
    $_REQUEST['email'], 
    $_REQUEST['password'],
});
```

and call authentication function in your necessary page

Comment: You can just add `$request` as parameter